# Error on order grid when searching "Order ID" - Report

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi when searching by order ID on the order grid I get an error report and I am unsure where to begin with getting to the root of the issue! Searching by email etc is fine!

Magento 1.9.1 with all patches

````
a:5:{i:0;s:275:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '`main_table`.increment_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT main_table.entity_id) FROM `sales_flat_order_grid` AS `main_table` WHERE (```main_table```.`increment_id` LIKE '%10000%')";i:1;s:7508:"#0 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(756): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/local/Xtento/EnhancedGrid/Model/Grid/Rewrite.php(316) : eval()'d code(38): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Model_Sales_Order_Grid_Collection->getSize()
#8 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(522): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(569): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_renderLimit()
#11 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(533): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/Grid.php(61): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/local/Xtento/EnhancedGrid/Model/Grid/Rewrite.php(316) : eval()'d code(85): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/local/Xtento/EnhancedGrid/Model/Grid/Rewrite.php(316) : eval()'d code(95): Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Block_Rewrite_Sales_Order_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/local/Xtento/EnhancedGrid/Model/Grid/Processor.php(122): Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Block_Rewrite_Sales_Order_Grid->xtPrepareCollection()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/local/Xtento/EnhancedGrid/Model/Observer.php(22): Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Model_Grid_Processor->processBlock(Object(Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Block_Rewrite_Sales_Order_Grid))
#17 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1339): Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Model_Observer->adminhtmlBlockHtmlBefore(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#18 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1318): Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Xtento_EnhancedGrid_Model_Observer), 'adminhtmlBlockH...', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
#19 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(448): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('adminhtml_block...', Array)
#20 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(80): Mage::dispatchEvent('adminhtml_block...', Array)
#21 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#24 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid/Container.php(77): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#25 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid/container.phtml(36): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container->getGridHtml()
#26 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#27 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#28 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#32 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#33 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#34 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#35 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#36 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#37 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#38 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#39 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#40 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#41 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#42 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#43 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#44 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(95): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#45 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->indexAction()
#46 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#47 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#48 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#49 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#50 /var/www/vhosts/mydomainreplaced/httpdocs/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')
#51 {main}";s:3:"url";s:74:"/index.php/spadmin/sales_order/index/key/d300aef9496bcd3723dd85cf393e9298/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"admin";}
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have `Xtento_EnhancedGrid`. Make sure it is not conflicting with other extensions or maybe it is buggy.

Try disabling it from `app/etc/modules/Xtento_EnhancedGrid.xml` by setting `<active>` to `false`.

Empty your cache and try again.

Comment: I had to install the latest version of this plugin which fixed the issue thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like something removed the column `increment_id` from the `sales_flat_order_grid` table. In a vanilla 1.9 installation, the table looks like this:

```
+---------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field               | Type                 | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| entity_id           | int(10) unsigned     | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| status              | varchar(32)          | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| store_id            | smallint(5) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| store_name          | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| customer_id         | int(10) unsigned     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| base_grand_total    | decimal(12,4)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| base_total_paid     | decimal(12,4)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| grand_total         | decimal(12,4)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| total_paid          | decimal(12,4)        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| increment_id        | varchar(50)          | YES  | UNI | NULL    |       |
| base_currency_code  | varchar(3)           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| order_currency_code | varchar(255)         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| shipping_name       | varchar(255)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| billing_name        | varchar(255)         | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| created_at          | timestamp            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| updated_at          | timestamp            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
+---------------------+----------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I don't know this `Xtento/EnhancedGrid` extension, but it might be related.